# Are Tweens also Sprites?

Tags: cocos2d-x, game-engine, phaser-framework, melonjs

What is the difference between a sprite and a tween?  When do you use one or the other in game development?  I'm making a game and can't find a good explanation about the difference about the two.

Answer (score 1):

A *sprite* is a visual component. A character, enemy, collectable, or projectile are all examples of sprites; at least visually.

*Tween* is short for *in between*, and deals more with interpolation between two states. Tweens are composed of a timer, an interpolation function, and the start and end states. Some examples of tweens are: fading between colors, rotation between two angles, and motion between two points.

In short, a tween is a method of dynamically creating all of the steps between two states for the purpose of animation; It inherently has a temporal component. In contrast to a sprite, which is basically just an image.

We use a popular tween library in melonJS called Tween.js - Their examples should give a pretty good sense of what tweens are for: https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/#examples

---

melonJS provides both sprites and tweens as separate classes. [`me.Sprite`](http://melonjs.github.io/melonJS/docs/me.Sprite.html) and [`me.Tween`](http://melonjs.github.io/melonJS/docs/me.Tween.html). Sprite is one of the base classes for objects that draw an image to the screen; an example subclass is [`me.AnimationSheet`](http://melonjs.github.io/melonJS/docs/me.AnimationSheet.html) Which simplifies the task of flipping between images to create a flipbook-style animation.

There are a few internal uses of tweens in melonJS, apart from being a public API; The scene transitions (fade to black and so on) are created with tweens.

And I made use of tweens in some of my melonJS games. The sliding doors in [Sprung Fever](http://blipjoy.github.io/sprung_fever/public/index.html) are created with a tween. Here's the code for that: https://github.com/blipjoy/sprung_fever/blob/834b6ad27e45bf2a8fa80894ad12ddfa5b35aa2a/public/js/entities/door.js#L21-L29